# Mapping MapOf - UserDefinedType to POJO in cassandra using Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-annotations, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following user defined type in cassandra:

```
CREATE TYPE key(
    name text,
    created_time timestamp
);
```

It goes in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE keys(
    id uuid,
    keys map<text, frozen<list<key>>>
);
```

** Note that the below POJOS also contain setters/getters, snipped for readability**

Then I have the following POJO for mapping for `key`:

```
@UserDefinedType(value = "key")
public class MyKey {
    @Column(value = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(value = "created_time")
    private Instant createdTime;
}
```

I have the following POJO for `keys`

```
@Table(value = "keys")
public class MyKeys {
    @PrimaryKey(value = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @Column(value = "keys")
    private Map<String, List<Key>> keys;
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to insert an instance of `MyKeys` I get the following error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Only primitive types are allowed inside Collections for property [keys] of type [interface java.util.Map] in entity [com.utx.dao.tables.MyKeys]

Does the Spring-Data-Cassandra mapper not work with maps of user defined types, and if not, is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: That's a [current limitation](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-409) of Spring Data for Apache Cassandra in the `Map` type support.

Comment: @mp911de do you know of any workaround(s)?

Comment: Try adding `@FrozenValue` annotation on top of `keys` field

Comment: To workaround you can create your own data type, which consists of map key and map value. Then use List of user defined type as a field in your dto.